# how to compress multiple folders into one with batch file

Tags: batch-file, compression, rar

i have a batch file to compress one folder and rename it with date & time and it's working well.

now i need same file to compress more than one folder into one compressed rar file.

here is my batch:

```
@echo off
echo STARTING BACKUP...
echo %date% %time%
echo+

:: variables
set src=D:\test
set dest=D:\Backups

set filename=%DATE:/=-%_%TIME::=-%
set filename=%filename: =%
Set Rar=%ProgramFiles%\WinRar\WinRAR.exe

"%Rar%" a -m5 -ed -pEltyar -r %dest%\%filename%.rar "%src%"

echo Backup Completed!
@pause
```

Comment: For a single command line solution using just `Rar.exe` or `WinRAR.exe` and nothing else see the answer on [How to compress multiple folders into one rar with batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484300/3074564)

Comment: @Mofi thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```dos
@echo off
Title Compress multi-folders in one with Winrar
Mode 70,5 & color 0A
echo STARTING BACKUP...
Call :GetFileNameWithDateTime
echo %filename%

:: variables
set src="D:\test1","D:\test2"
set dest=D:\Backups

If not exist "%dest%" MD "%dest%"

Set Rar=%ProgramFiles%\WinRar\RAR.exe

for /f "delims=," %%i in ('echo %src%') do (
    "%Rar%" a -inul -m5 -ed -hpEltyar -r "%dest%\%filename%.rar" "%%~i"
)
If "%errorlevel%" EQU "0" (
    echo(
    echo Backup Completed Successfully !
) Else (
    echo( & color 0C
    echo There was an error occured !
)
Timeout /T 10 /nobreak>nul & exit

::*********************************************************************************************
:GetFileNameWithDateTime
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set "filename=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%-%MyDate:~8,2%-%MyDate:~10,2%"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Did you get any error message ? can you explain more your issue ?

Comment: no i didn't get any error, it says backup complete and there is no files compressed in the folder

Comment: You should modifie this line to yours `set src="D:\test1","D:\test2","D:\test3","D:\test4","D:\test5"`
Did you change it to yours ?

Comment: sure, i have two folders `set src="D:\test1","D:\test2"`

Comment: @MuhammadS.Eltyar Please Check my edit code and tell me how it works on your side ?

Comment: it's not working and giving `There was an error occured !`

Comment: is there a possible solution ?