# How to compress multiple folders into one rar archive file with batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I try to get my batch file to compress more than one folder into one compressed file but with no success. It only works with one folder like that `set src="D:\test1"`. Can anyone help please?

Here is my batch:

```
@echo off
echo STARTING BACKUP...
echo %date% %time%
echo+

:: variables
set src="D:\test1" + "D:\test2" + "D:\test3"
set dest=D:\Backups

set filename=%DATE:/=-%_%TIME::=-%
set filename=%filename: =%
Set Rar=%ProgramFiles%\WinRar\WinRAR.exe

"%Rar%" a -m5 -ed -pEltyar -r %dest%\%filename%.rar "%src%"

echo Backup Completed!
@pause
```

Comment: What happens if you just run this line? `"%ProgramFiles%\WinRar\WinRAR.exe" a -m5 -ed -pEltyar -r D:\Backups\test.rar ""D:\test1" + "D:\test2" + "D:\test3""`. If it doesn't create a file named `test.rar` in `D:\Backups` containing what you needed, then the issue is with your lack of knowledge on how to use `WinRAR`, not with the batch file. I would suggest therefore that you read the usage information for WinRAR, then test with the bare command line until you get it to work. Once you've achieved that you can work backwards to structure the batch script as needed to propagate that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very often useful to read the manual on using an application. The manual for console version `Rar.exe` is the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR*. It can be opened by double clicking on this file with primary (left) mouse button. The text manual can be read from top to bottom to build the command line required for a specific compression or extraction task.

The manual for GUI version `WinRAR.exe` is the help file `WinRAR.chm` which can be also opened by double clicking on this file or from within an already running *WinRAR* by clicking in last menu **Help** on first menu item **Help topics**. The first help tab **Contents** contains the list item **Command line mode** with listing structured and already right ordered the help pages being useful to build the command line for a specific task.

The **entire** batch file written by you can be replaced by a single command line:

With using the console version `Rar.exe`:

```
@"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -agYYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM -cfg- -ed -ep1 -inul -m5 -pEltyar -r -y -- D:\Backups\ "D:\test1" "D:\test2" "D:\test3"
```

Replace switch `-inul` for example by `-idcp` or `-idcdp` if you want to see what `Rar.exe` is doing while running this command line.

With using the GUI version `WinRAR.exe`:

```
@"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -agYYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM -cfg- -ed -ep1 -ibck -m5 -pEltyar -r -y -- D:\Backups\ "D:\test1" "D:\test2" "D:\test3"
```

I would suggest to use `D:\Backups\Backup_.rar` instead of just `D:\Backups\` to create the RAR archives with file name `Backup_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM.rar` instead of just `YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM.rar`, but that's your choice.

Comment: thank you very much it's working perfect and i appreciate your advice.